# BFD issue with BGP support on Cisco 9396PX

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, bgp, bfd

I have following BGP configuration and trying to reduce my convergence time with help of `BFD` but having hard time.

```
router bgp 1111
  log-neighbor-changes
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    network 22.22.22.0/24
  neighbor 11.11.11.1
    bfd
    remote-as 2222
    update-source loopback160
    ebgp-multihop 2
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      send-community
```

This is what i did to enable BFD

```
feature bfd
bfd interval 500 min_rx 500 multiplier 5
bfd echo-interface loopback160
!
router bgp 1111
  neighbor 11.11.11.1
    bfd
```

Now when i run (no output), that means BGP isn't registered to BFD, if i enable OSFP then i can see some output in show bfd neighbors command. I tried debug and no output in debug logs. trying to understand why BGP not getting registered. (My peer ISP did enabled BDF their side) my nxos version is 7.0(3)I4(7)

```
# show bfd neighbors
#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### NX-OS 7.x likely does not support BFD BGP Multihop

BFD BGP multihop support was introduced in NX-OS 8.1(1) according to the [NX-OS 7K Command Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus7000/sw/interfaces/command/cisco_nexus7000_interfaces_command_ref/b_commands.html#wp8482323790).

BFD BGP multihop support was introduced in NX-OS 9.2(1) according to the [NX-OS 9K Command Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/92x/interfaces/configuration/guide/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x_chapter_0110.html#id_73468).

The [NX-OS 5.x Command Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/5_x/nx-os/interfaces/configuration/guide/if_cli/if_bfd.html#58316) explicitly calls out support for only for single-hop EBGP and iBGP peers.

Finally, multi-hop is only supported on the newer ASIC's (-EX and newer) and not the 9396PX hardware platform, according to the [Guidelines and Limitations for BFD Multihop](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/92x/interfaces/configuration/guide/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x_chapter_0110.html#id_73791) in the NX-OS 9K Command Guide.  Thanks, [@rnxrx](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1172/rnxrx) for pointing this out as well.

---

You should be able verify by looking for the multihop command:

### Example

```
R1(config)# bfd ?
    echo-interface    Configure interface used for bfd echo frames
    echo-rx-interval  Configure BFD session echo rx interval
    interval          Configure BFD session interval parameters
    ipv4              Ipv4 sessions
    ipv6              Ipv6 sessions
    multihop          Configure BFD Multihop session interval parameters
    slow-timer        Configure slow mode timer for sessions
    startup-timer     Configure Delayed Start Up timer for sessions
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but this still won't help him - multi-hop is only supported on the newer ASIC's (-EX and newer) and not the 9396PX he mentions.   See https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/92x/interfaces/configuration/guide/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x_chapter_0110.html#id_73468 and search for guidelines and limitations.

Comment: @TDurden, Yes i don't have `multihop` option in command-line. I thought even i don't have multi-hop support but atleast i should see something on `show bfd neighbors` command right? In lab i have created BGP session on physical interface without any multihop even in that case i didn't see any output in `show bfd neighbors` (feel like something is missing here)

Comment: @rnxrx - Sounds like Satish has multiple obstacles to overcome.  The ASIC limitation is a great catch.  Do you mind if I integrate your comment into my answer?

Comment: @Satish, are you using identical hardware in your test?  Or are you using CML images?  I was able to lab your configuration with NX-OS 9000v 9.3(2) code and was able to see a result for the '''show bfd neighbors''' command.  I suggest you verify reachability between your bfd source interfaces.

Comment: I am using real Cisco nexus switches in my lab (CML doesn't support BFD i believe), i have CML also so i can give it a shot there also. (If OSPF is working with BFD then BGP should work also that is what i believe, i can understand it won't support multi-hop but it should show something atleast)

Comment: I have tried this on CML and as soon as i enable `bfd` on BGP peer i can see neighbors in `show bfd neighbors` command. that is not the case with Cisco nexus 9396PX hardware. (cisco isn't clear about this in document)

Comment: @Satish Are you running IPv6 or VRFs?  The required show command may be slightly different.

Comment: No, we don't have ipv6 or any fancy or complex configuration. everything in single VRF default. (no VxLAN or anything)

Comment: @Satish, I can reproduce in lab the lack of output from the '''show bfd neighbors''' command by removing some of the required BFD configuration.  I recommend reviewing the full configuration.  BGP, Loopbacks, BFD timers and expected reachability.  Also, check any ACLs to which may be blocking BFD.   http://kemot-net.com/blog/nexus-ibgp-with-bfd has an example ACL.

Comment: @Satish, I would recommend opening a TAC case if you are confident on the configuration.

Comment: Sorry i have deleted my previous comments because its not totally true, If i load nx-os version on eve-ng then it works but sometime it doesn't work, so i don't trust that, is nx-os 9.x are stable for production then i can load it on switch and try.

Comment: @TDurden when you have time can you post your CML working example of BFD, i would like to see what you did because in my CML my BFD not coming up even i specified update-interface in BGP. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110741/discussion-between-tdurden-and-satish).

Comment: @TDurden - help yourself!  To the additional points, though, this is one of the pitfalls of the 9Kv.  There are certain features which are specifically tied to the forwarding hardware.  The T2/ALE ASIC's in his switch have markedly different capabilities than the Cloudscale (EX/FX/FX2/GX) boxes that followed.  There are actually things you can do in the old boxes that you can't in the new ones, but far more things in the new ones that were never implemented in the old ones.  Given that BFD processing needs to be in hardware it's no wonder it doesn't simulate well.

Comment: Update: if i set `update-source Ethernet1/2` in BGP then it works but if i do `update-source loopback0` it failed (so it is clear multi-hop is not supported and not giving you any output in `show bfd neighbors`